# Using Adams-Bashforth method in Matlab to solve Lorenz-System Equation

Tags: matlab

I am trying to use my second order Adams-Bashforth function here:

```
function [t,x] = Adams(f,t_max,x0,N)
  h = t_max/N;
  t = linspace(0,t_max,N+1);  
  x = zeros(2,N+1);
  x(:,1) = x0;
  x(:,2) = x0 + h.*(f(t(1),x(:,1)));
  for i=2:N
    x(:,i+1) = x(:,i) + h.*((3/2.*f(t(i),x(:,i))-(1/2).*f(t(i-1),x(:,i-1)))); 
  end
end
```

In order to solve the Lorenz System Equation. However, whenever I try to call the function, I get an error.

```
sigma = 10;
beta = 8/3;
rho = 28;
f = @(t,a) [-sigma*a(1) + sigma*a(2); rho*a(1) - a(2) - a(1)*a(3); -beta*a(3) + a(1)*a(2)];
[t,a] = Adams(f,10,[1 1 1],100);
plot3(a(:,1),a(:,2),a(:,3))
```

Output:
"Unable to perform assignment because
the size of the left side is 2-by-1 and
the size of the right side is 1-by-3.

Error in Project>Adams (line 55)
x(:,1) = x0;"

Is the issue with my function, or with how I am calling my function? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why does `f=@(t,...` is expected to have an input `t`, but it is mussing in the expression of `f`?

Answer (score 0):

in line 5 of your Adams function:   `x(:,1) = x0;`

the input `x0` is the initial conditions `[1 1 1]` a row vector of size [3x1], but `x` is an array of size `zeros(2,N+1)`, or [2x101].

There are several mistakes here, the first you assign a row vector to a colon vector, not only that, but the size of the container in that  first column of array  `x` which is [2x1] , that is a different size than the size of `x0`. that is what the error tells you.

The function is buggy there , and it wont work unless you debug it according to the original intent of that method you are trying to implement.

note that also in the script f=@(t,... is expected to have an input `t`, but there is not `t` in the expression `[-sigma*a(1) + sigma*a(2); rho*a(1) - a(2) - a(1)*a(3); -beta*a(3) + a(1)*a(2)];`